# Renumeration vs Remuneration (reimbursed financially), which is correct?

Tags: synonyms, errors

For my entire life, I thought the correct word was Renumeration. But after reading a document that used Remuneration I checked google and apparently I was wrong.

The oxford dictionary has a link to Remuneration under the entry for Renumeration but it neglects to say why.

Are they both interchangable? I live in the UK, if it is a regional thing.

Comment: remuneration. I remember the order of "m" and "n" because it's the same as in "money," however I just looked it up and the two words don't seem to actually come from the same source.

Comment: It's a common misspelling.  But "renumeration" means "the act of renumbering".

Comment: "... thought the correct word was Renumeration" for what?  What made you think *Renumeration* was a word? Maybe you (?mis-)read the word the first time on?

Comment: **The word "remuneration" is often misspelled as "renumeration", which simply means counting or re-counting.** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remuneration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the OED *renumeration / remuneration* **are** interchangeable.  So too are the associated verbs -  *renumerate / remunerate*.  However, some commentators have strong feelings about renumeration being used with its first-cited meaning (i.e. *remuneration*, see below) "*... to be avoided at all costs is the metathesized form renumeration."* (R. W. Burchfield New Fowler's Mod. Eng. Usage (1996) 666/2).  *Remuneration* is much more commonly used than *renumeration* (https://goo.gl/44GQRa).

***Remuneration*** is first cited c.1400, comes from Middle French  (*remuneracion*) and Latin *(remūnerātiō),* and means *reward, recompense; (now usually) money paid for work or a service; payment, pay*.

**Continuously since the mid 16th century** *renumeration / renumerate* have been used with the same meaning as *remuneration / remunerate*.

Since 1596, ***renumeration*** has also meant '*the action or an instance of numbering* or *enumerating again*'.  This is widely held to be it's primary meaning.

The OED suggests that *renumeration* with the meaning of *remuneration* is a variant by metathesis (https://goo.gl/lhMZQh) arising from a folk-etymological association with words in *numer*-.

Comment: -1 Usage: "Late 16th cent." (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/renumeration) -- not today.

Comment: @Kris - I'm puzzled.  I say in my post that the first OED citation for renumeration is 1572 (meaning 1) and 1596 (meaning 2).  Isn't that late 16th century?

Comment: That's a different story from "Usage: 'Late 16th cent.'" -- origin versus currency. Many words/phrases have their origin centuries ago and yet are current today. Hope I'm clearer now.

Comment: @Kris - sorry, no, I don't follow.

Comment: Dan, Say, a word has been first used in 1572. It has been in use ever since, and is in use today. Compare: A word has been first used in 1600 and its last recorded use was in 1790; it's not in use any more in contemporary English anywhere in the world. -- We do have such lost words and dated usages.

Comment: @kris - I thought that was that was what you meant, which is why I am puzzled, because the OED post multiple citations over the centuries and I post their most recent (2002) in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [my dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/renumeration) defines *renumeration* as "Misspelling of remuneration".

Comment: Please use comments option.

Answer (score 2):

When I started looking into this, I absolutely thought it was renumeration. [Turns out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remuneration%2Crenumeration&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cremuneration%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bremuneration%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRemuneration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crenumeration%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brenumeration%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRenumeration%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRENUMERATION%3B%2Cc0) Remuneration is **WAY** more popular. The OED website has the first recorded use of [Remuneration](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/162337?redirectedFrom=remuneration#eid) at circa 1400 and of [Renumeration](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/274285?rskey=EOOOFh&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) over 150 years later. There is noted controversy over the use of "Remuneration", but only from a single source, listed by @Dan above.

Given that "remuneration" is used more than a 100 times more frequently in literature than "renumeration" (according to Ngram, linked above), I would say that answers your question. It also has a more logical etymological root, coming from the Latin *remūnerātiō*, meaning the same. "Renumeration" appears to lack any etymological root other than "probably formed via metathesis from "Remuneration".

It's going to take an awful long time for me to get used to it though...

Comment: Actually, "renumeration" is a legitimate word, adding the prefix "re-" to the word "numeration".  But the meaning is "the act of renumbering".

Comment: @HotLicks, I see what you mean - the two existed separately but the meaning of remuneration was absorbed at a later date by renumeration?

Comment: "Renumeration" was erroneously used instead of "remuneration", and somehow that use "stuck".  Likely it was used erroneously in some textbook or maybe some law or regulation and "caught on" from there.

Comment: @Dan, entirely agree where the second has become more commonplace, but remuneration appears to be far more prevalent in literature.

Comment: As it should be.  Using "renumeration" to mean the same as "remuneration" is an error.  And using "renumeration" to mean "the act of renumbering" is simply rare.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that any uses of these words that we find from ca 1500 were originally written out in longhand by the author (who may or may not have had good handwriting), then typeset by a printer who may or may not have been very good at spelling.  Consider what "remuneration" would look like in slightly loopy longhand and tell me that a typesetter unfamiliar with the word would get it set correctly, every time.

Looking through old books with Ngram I have on a number of occasions seen obvious spelling errors.  "Renumeration" when is should be "remuneration" is simply a less-obvious spelling error.